# In setData QTableView routine using pyqt4, how to store value retrieved from QTableView cell to my arraydata?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview

I have created a QTableView that is editable by the user. I am trying to retrieve the data from the QTableView cell after I double click the cell and edit it in the GUI. However, when I double click the cell, make my edit, and hit enter, I get the following error:

in setData
    self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()] = value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Here is my code:

```
class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None, *args): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args) 
        self.arraydata = datain

    def rowCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.arraydata)  

    def columnCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.arraydata[0]) 

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(self.arraydata[row][column])
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self.arraydata[row][column] 
            return QtCore.QVariant(value)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                row = index.row()
                column = index.column()
                self.arraydata[row][column] = value
                return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

`self.arraydata[row][column] = value` is where the issue is in `setdata` routine. I've tried converting `value` to a `str` or a `QString`. I've also tried using `.toString()` and `.toPyObject()`. But none seem to work. I'm not sure what else to do to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, what is the structure of `arraydata`? The error suggests it is a list of strings, rather than a list of lists. Try putting `print(repr(self.arraydata))` before the offending line, and check to see what is actually there...

Comment: You were right, I was sending in a list of strings rather than a list of lists. Sending in a list of lists solves my problem. Thanks so much for pointing this out!